# How would the relationships work within this social network problem

Tags: mysql

1) Consider the social network below. In this network nodes represent person and links represents friendships. For example, A and B are friends, and there is a link between A and B. You want to have a database to store your user profiles (id, fname, lname, email, gender, password-you can use node node names as ids), and users’s interests (a person can have multiple interests), and their friendship connections

Answer (score 0):

You would have the following:

```
Users
-------
id fname, lname, etc etc

Interests
--------------
id user_id content

Friendships
-----------------
user_id friend_id
```

The key here is that the friendship table is self referential in that friend_id is actually a foreign key to the user's id.